# How to remove a row from a 2d array from user input

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to remove a row from a 2d array from a user input. I get the idea of having a copy array to overwrite the original 2d array but I cant seem to find the syntax to do it. Plus I want the copy array to then overwrite the original array so that the other methods won't be affected.

```java
static String data[][] = new String[3][100];
int max = 0;

static void start() {
    p2("---INVENTORY OPTIONS---");
    p2("1. VIEW Inventory");
    p2("2. ADD Product(Name, Price, Quantity)");
    p2("3. UPDATE Product(Name, Price, Quantity)");
    p2("4. DELETE Product(Name, Price, Quantity)");
    p1("Enter inventory option: ");
    String q2a = stringscan();

    if (q2a.equals("1")) {
        invview();
    } else if (q2a.equals("2")) {
        invadd(q2a);
    } else if (q2a.equals("3")) {
        invupdate(q2a);
    } else if (q2a.equals("4")) {
        invdelete(q2a);
    }
}

static void invupdate(String q2a) {
    if (q2a.equals("3")) {
        p1("Input Product name to update: ");
        String edit = stringscan();
        for (int i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {
            if (data[0][i].contains(edit)) {
                System.out.print("Edit or Retain Product Name [" + i + "]: ");
                String qname = stringscan();
                data[0][i] = qname;

                System.out.print("Edit or Retain Product Price [" + i + "]: ");
                String qprice = stringscan();
                data[1][i] = qprice;

                System.out.print("Edit or Retain Product Quantity [" + i + "]: ");
                String qqty = stringscan();
                data[2][i] = qqty;
            }
        }
        invview();
        start();
    }
}

int[][] copy = new int[data.length - 1][data.length - 1];
static void invdelete(String q2a) {
    if (q2a.equals("4")) {
        p1("Input Product name to delete: ");
        String edit = stringscan();
        for (int i = 1, j = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {
            if (!data[0][i].contains(edit)) {
                ///how to remove row from 2d array
            }
        }
        invview();
        start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you **have to** use a 2D Array? Using an ArrayList or List Interface makes this sort of thing so much easier.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to delete an array from that

Comment: Yes 2d array is needed because the product name is connected with its product price and product quantity

Answer (score 0):

To make this task somewhat easier and more flexable, the first thing you might want to do is create a class of **Product**, for example:

```
public class Products {
    
    // Hold instances of Products
    public static java.util.List<Products> products = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    
    // Instance (class member) variables
    private String productName;
    private double productPrice;
    private int    productQuantity;

    // Constructor #1:
    public Products() {   
        products.add((this));
    }

    // Constructor #2:
    public Products(String name, double price, int quantity) {
        this.productName = name;
        this.productPrice = price;
        this.productQuantity = quantity;
        products.add((this));
    }

    // Getters and Setters
    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public double getProductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public void setProductPrice(double productPrice) {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }

    public int getProductQuantity() {
        return productQuantity;
    }

    public void setProductQuantity(int productQuantity) {
        this.productQuantity = productQuantity;
    }

    public static java.util.List<Products> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    // Public class Utility Methods
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder(productName).append(", ").append(String.valueOf(productPrice))
                                 .append(", ").append(String.valueOf(productQuantity)).toString();
    }
    
    public static String toStringTable() {
        StringBuilder productsTable = new StringBuilder("        --- Products Table ---");
        productsTable.append(System.lineSeparator());
        String header = String.format(java.util.Locale.US, "%-20s %-10s %-8s %n", "Product Name", "Price", "Quantity");
        productsTable.append(header);
        String underline = String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(header.length()-3, "="));
        productsTable.append(underline).append(System.lineSeparator());
        for (Products p : products) {
            String tableRow = String.format(java.util.Locale.US, "%-20s %-10.2f %-8d %n", 
                    p.getProductName(), p.getProductPrice(), p.getProductQuantity());
            productsTable.append(tableRow);
        }
        productsTable.append(underline);
        return productsTable.toString();
    }
    
    public static boolean loadProducts(String filePath) {
        try (java.util.Scanner reader = new java.util.Scanner(new java.io.File(filePath))) {
            Products.products.clear();
            while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = reader.nextLine().trim();
                if (line.isEmpty() || line.startsWith("#")) {
                    continue;
                }
                String[] lineParts = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");
                String name = lineParts[0];
                double price = Double.valueOf(lineParts[1].isEmpty() ? "0.0" : lineParts[1]);
                int qty = Integer.valueOf(lineParts[2].isEmpty() ? "0" : lineParts[2]);
                Products tmp = new Products(name, price, qty);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("Products.loadProducts() Method Error!")
                    .log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public static boolean saveProducts(String filePath) {
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File(filePath);
        try (java.io.FileWriter fw = new java.io.FileWriter(file)) {
            // creates the file
            file.createNewFile();
            fw.write("# --- Products File ---" + System.lineSeparator());
            for (Products p : Products.products) {
                fw.write(p.toString() + System.lineSeparator());
                fw.flush();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("Products.saveProducts() Method Error!")
                             .log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This of course then means that changes would need to be made to the main operational body of your code to take advantage of the fact that instances of **Products** is contained within a [List Inteface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) for easier addition and deletion from the actual collection created. Using a collection mechanism (like a List) allows you grow or reduce its size dynamically whereas with an **Array** you are dealt with handling a fixed size object and need to pretty much jump through hoops (so to speak) to modify *add to* or d*elete from* them.

Utilizing the class provided above along with the code provided below you will end up with a basic ***runnable*** Products Inventory console application. The first thing you may notice when the code is run is that the main menu is a little larger. Instead of four (4) menu items, there are now seven (7) menu items. Menu items such as **LOAD Inventory**, **SAVE Inventory**, and **QUIT** have been added.

The main menu is always displayed once a menu task (other than quit) has been completed. This of course allows for continuous operation of the application without the need to re-run it. Products can be added to, changed, or deleted from the Inventory as needed. A table of Products within the Inventory can also always be viewed at any time. The products added can also be saved to a Products file within the local file system. This file name is currently hard-coded as "Products.txt" which should be changed to reflect the needs of the User. Hard-coding something like this is never really a good idea but is done here merely for demonstration simplicity.

Read any and all comments in code before deleting them:

```
public class Inventory {
    
    // Class Field variables
    private final java.util.Scanner USERINPUT = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    private final String NL = System.lineSeparator();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Inventory().start();
    }
    
    private void start() {
        //Main Menu...
        String q2a = "";
        /* WHILE loops are used for all prompts so that validity 
           checks can be done and the User has the oportunity to
           make a correct entry.                             */
        while (!q2a.equals("7")) {
            p2("---INVENTORY OPTIONS---");
            p2("1. LOAD Inventory");
            p2("2. VIEW Inventory");
            p2("3. ADD Product(Name, Price, Quantity)");
            p2("4. UPDATE Product(Name, Price, Quantity)");
            p2("5. DELETE Product(Name, Price, Quantity)");
            p2("6. SAVE Inventory");
            p2("7. QUIT");
            p1("Enter inventory option: --> ");
            q2a = stringscan();
            // Validate User Input...
            // Only a single digit from 1 to 7 is acceptable.
            if (!q2a.matches("[1-7]")) {
                p3("Invalid menu choice! Try again...");
                p2("");  // Add a blank line to console window.
                continue;   // Redisplay main menu
            }
            p2("");

            // Process Menu Selection...
            switch (q2a) {
                // Load Inventory
                case "1":
                    invload("Products.txt");
                    p2("");
                    break;
                // View Products Table
                case "2":
                    invview();
                    p4();
                    break;
                // Add to Products
                case "3":
                    invadd();
                    break;
                // Change a Product item
                case "4":
                    invupdate();
                    break;
                // Delete a Product Item
                case "5":
                    invdelete();
                    break;
                // Save Products List to file
                case "6":
                    invsave("Products.txt");
                    p2("");
                    break;
                // Quit the application.
                case "7":
                    p2("Quiting...Bye-Bye");
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    // User Input request.
    private String stringscan() {
        return USERINPUT.nextLine();
    }
    
    // Console 'print'
    private void p1(String text) {
        System.out.print(text);
    }

    // Console 'println'
    private void p2(String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }

    // Console 'err.println'
    private void p3(String text) {
        System.err.println(text);
    }

    // Console 'Enter To Continue' prompt
    private void p4() {
        p2("<< Press ENTER to continue >>");
        stringscan();
    }

    // Display Products Table to Console.
    private void invview() {
        // See if the instances List actually contains anything:
        if (Products.products.isEmpty()) {
            p3("There are no Products yet to view!");
            p2("");
            return;
        }

        p2(Products.toStringTable());
    }

    private void invadd() {
        String name = "";
        // Product Name Prompt...
        while (name.isEmpty()) {
            p1("What is the product Name you want to add? --> ");
            name = stringscan().trim();
        }
        
        // Is the Product already in the List?
        for (Products p : Products.products) {
            String pName = p.getProductName();
            if (pName.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                // Yes it is so inform User and get out of here.
                p3("The product named '" + pName + "' is already contained" + NL
                   + "within the Products Inventory List!" + NL);
                return;
            }
        }

        // Product Price Prompt...
        String priceString = "";
        while (priceString.isEmpty()) {
            p1("What is the product price? --> ");
            priceString = stringscan().trim();
            // Validate User Input...
            /* The Regular Expression used in the String#matches() method
               validates the fact that a string representation of a signed 
               or unsigned numerical Integer or floating point value is
               indeed supplied. If not the User is prompted again.      */
            if (!priceString.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
                p3("Invalid price supplied! Try again...");
                p2("");
                priceString = "";
            }
        }
        // Convert string numerical value to double data type.
        double price = Double.valueOf(priceString);

        // Product Quantity Prompt...
        String quantityString = "";
        while (quantityString.isEmpty()) {
            p1("What is the product quantity? --> ");
            quantityString = stringscan().trim();
            // Validate User Input...
            /* The Regular Expression used in the String#matches() method
               validates the fact that a string representation of a signed 
               or unsigned numerical Integer value is indeed supplied. If 
               not the User is prompted again.      */
            if (!quantityString.matches("-?\\d+")) {
                p3("Invalid quantity supplied! Try again...");
                p2("");
                priceString = "";
            }
        }
        // Convert string numerical value to int data type.
        int quantity = Integer.valueOf(quantityString);

        /* Create an instance of this product which ultimately 
           gets stored within the Products List (products). */
        Products products = new Products(name, price, quantity);
        // Inform User of successful product addition.
        p2("Product was added to inventory!");
        p2("");
    }

    private void invupdate() {
        // Are the actually products in inventory to update?
        if (Products.products.isEmpty()) {
            // No...Inform User and get out of here.
            p3("There are no Products yet to update!");
            p2("");
            return;
        }
        p2("--- Product Update ---");
        String pName = "";
        while (pName.isEmpty()) {
            p1("Enter the Product name to update (q to go-back): --> ");
            pName = stringscan();
            if (pName.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                p2("");
                return;
            }
            boolean foundProduct = false;
            for (Products p : Products.products) {
                String productName = p.getProductName();
                double productPrice = p.getProductPrice();
                int productQuantity = p.getProductQuantity();
                // Find the desired product...
                if (productName.equalsIgnoreCase(pName)) {
                    // Product Found...
                    // Change Product Name?
                    foundProduct = true;
                    p2("Enter new Product Name for '" + productName + "' or");
                    p1("just hit ENTER to keep it: --> ");
                    pName = stringscan();
                    if (pName.isEmpty()) {
                        pName = productName;
                    }

                    // Change Product Price?
                    String pPrice = "";
                    while (pPrice.isEmpty()) {
                        p2("");
                        p2("Enter a new Product Price for '" + pName + "' or");
                        p1("just hit ENTER to keep the old price of [$"
                                + productPrice + "]: --> ");
                        pPrice = stringscan();
                        if (pPrice.isEmpty()) {
                            pPrice = String.valueOf(productPrice);
                        }
                        if (!pPrice.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
                            p3("Invalid price (" + pPrice + ") supplied! Try again...");
                            p3("");
                            pPrice = "";
                        }
                    }
                    double price = Double.valueOf(pPrice);

                    // Change Product Quantity?
                    String pQty = "";
                    while (pQty.isEmpty()) {
                        p2("");
                        p2("Enter a new Product Quantity for '" + pName + "' or");
                        p1("just hit ENTER to keep the old Quantity of ["
                                + productQuantity + "]: --> ");
                        pQty = stringscan();
                        if (pQty.isEmpty()) {
                            pQty = String.valueOf(productQuantity);
                        }
                        else if (!pQty.matches("-?\\d+")) {
                            p3("Invalid price (" + pQty + ") supplied! Try again...");
                            p3("");
                            pQty = "";
                        }
                    }
                    int quantity = Integer.valueOf(pQty);
                    p.setProductName(pName);
                    p.setProductPrice(price);
                    p.setProductQuantity(quantity);
                    p2("Product was Updated!");
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!foundProduct) {
                p3("Could not locate the product named: " + pName + "! Try again...");
                p2("");
                pName = "";
            }

        }

        // View Products Table to show changes (if any):
        p2("");
        invview();
        p4();
    }

    private void invdelete() {
        // Are the actually products in inventory to delete?
        if (Products.products.isEmpty()) {
            // No...Inform User and get out of here.
            p3("There are no Products yet to delete!");
            p2("");
            return;
        }
        p2("--- Product Delete ---");
        String pName = "";
        while (pName.isEmpty()) {
            // Allow the option to cancel process by entering 'q'.
            p1("Enter the Product name to delete (q to go-back): --> ");
            pName = stringscan();
            // Was 'q' supplied to cancel process?
            if (pName.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                // Yes... get out of here.
                p2("");
                return;
            }

            // Find the desired Product (not letter case sensitive)
            boolean foundProduct = false;
            String productName = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < Products.products.size(); i++) {
                productName = Products.products.get(i).getProductName();
                if (productName.equalsIgnoreCase(pName)) {
                    foundProduct = true;
                    // Remove the Product from the Porducts List (products).
                    Products.products.remove(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Inform the User of the outcome.
            if (foundProduct) {
                p2("The Product (" + productName + ") was deleted!");
            }
            else {
                p3("Could not locate the product named: " + pName + "! Try again...");
                p2("");
                pName = "";
            }
        }

        // View Products Table to show deletions (if any):
        p2("");
        invview();
        p4();
    }

    private void invload(String filePath) {
        // See the the supplied Products file exists....
        if (!new java.io.File(filePath).exists()) {
            // No it doesn't so inform User and get out of here.
            p3("There is no Products file yet to load!");
            p3("");
            return;
        }
        // Load in all Products from the supplied products file.
        if (Products.loadProducts(filePath)) {
            p2("Products file loaded!");
            if (Products.products.isEmpty()) {
                p2("There were no products found within the Products file!");
            }
        }
    }

    private void invsave(String filePath) {
        /* See if there are actual products within the 
           Products List (products) to be saved...  */
        if (Products.products.isEmpty()) {
            // No there isn't so inform User and get out of here.
            p3("There are no Products yet to save!");
            p2("");
            return;
        }
        
        // Save all the products to the local file system.
        if (Products.saveProducts(filePath)) {
            p2("Products List Successfully Saved!");
        }
    }
}
```